# Excel table object reference not set

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I have two tables in my excel workbook which I am working with in a VSTO addin:

```
using Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools;    

Tools.Excel.ListObject contractTable;
Tools.Excel.ListObject feeTable;

contractTable = Globals.Sheet1.tblContractDetails;
feeTable = Globals.Sheet10.tblFeesData;
```

As far as I can tell both tables are set up and referenced in the same way. Intellisence picks up both tables and I can see them both as named ranges in my workbook. When I try to set an instance of the feeTable I get a Null reference exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

EDIT:
I was able to work around this issue as follows:

```
Excel.ListObject feeTable;
Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Fees"];
feeTable = ws.ListObjects["tblFeesData"];
```

Still very interested if anyone knows why these two tables would behave different ways?

Comment: Were both tables created the same way?

Comment: Yes - using add table in excel

Comment: Weird...  Any chance you can post your document, like to GDrive, SkyDrive, DropBox, etc?